# How do I open a new txt file using path

Tags: python

I want to make txt file using a variable where the user can input but if I use the code below, I think this code can only run when there's an existing file but I want to create a non-existing file. Any idea on how to do that?

```
import os.path

path ="~/Desktop/psp/student list"

name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of the file: ")

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt") 

f = open(completeName,'a')

f.close()
```

Comment: Look at desktop. Read folder name.

Comment: @timgeb do you have to do like 'C:/desktop/foldername' ? or how?

Comment: You say you want to determine the path to a folder on your desktop (for putting a file there). Nobody of us knows why you have a problem with that, because you did not explain what the problem is.

Comment: @timgeb I actually don't understand the concept of locating the folder for the path when creating txt file

Comment: So you don't know what a path is? Or do you not know how to get the path of a folder on your desktop?

Comment: @timgeb both actually

Comment: In that case I am afraid you need more help than we can provide.

Comment: @timgeb I kind of understand what a path is but I don't know how to get the path of folder in my desktop

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and now I assume your code has several problems.

1. variable name: save_path -(should be)-> path:
   Simply, the two names should be the same.
2. Absolute path should begin with '/Users...':
   This seems to be crucial.

You seem to use mac, and in the case of mac OSX, path string is like this. `/Users/<username>/Desktop/....`

Proper code would be like this, I think.

```
import os.path

path ="/Users/<your user name>/Desktop"
#If deeper, path string should be longer.

name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")
completeName = os.path.join(path, name_of_file+".txt")

f = open(completeName,'a')
f.close()
```

I tested this code on my mac, and found it works either with a new file name or with an existing file name.
Attention: I use Python3 and `input` is equivalent to Python2's `raw_input`.